# What is the usefulness of `enable_shared_from_this`?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, tr1

I ran across `enable_shared_from_this` while reading the Boost.Asio examples and after reading the documentation I am still lost for how this should correctly be used.  Can someone please give me an example and explanation of when using this class makes sense.

Comment: The simple explanation is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Answer (score 441, accepted):

It enables you to get a valid `shared_ptr` instance to `this`, when all you have is `this`. Without it, you would have no way of getting a `shared_ptr` to `this`, unless you already had one as a member. This example from the [boost documentation for enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html):

```
class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
public:

    shared_ptr<Y> f()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q = p->f();
    assert(p == q);
    assert(!(p < q || q < p)); // p and q must share ownership
}
```

The method `f()` returns a valid `shared_ptr`, even though it had no member instance. Note that you cannot simply do this:

```
class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
public:

    shared_ptr<Y> f()
    {
        return shared_ptr<Y>(this);
    }
}
```

The shared pointer that this returned will have a different reference count from the "proper" one, and one of them will end up losing and holding a dangling reference when the object is deleted.

`enable_shared_from_this` has become part of C++ 11 standard. You can also get it from there as well as from boost.

Comment: +1. The key point is that the "obvious" technique of just returning shared_ptr<Y>(this) is broken, because this winds up creating multiple distinct shared_ptr objects with separate reference counts. For this reason you must never create more than one shared_ptr **from the same raw pointer**.

Comment: It should be noted that in _C++11 and later_, it is **perfectly valid** to use a `std::shared_ptr` constructor on a _raw pointer_ **if** it inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this`. **I don' t know if** Boost's semantics were updated to support this.

Comment: @MatthewHolder Do you have a quote for this? On cppreference.com I read "Constructing a `std::shared_ptr` for an object that is already managed by another `std::shared_ptr` will not consult the internally stored weak reference and thus will lead to undefined behavior." (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: Why can't you just do `shared_ptr<Y> q = p`?

Comment: @DanM. AFAIK you can. I don't get the use case wither

Comment: @DanM. You can, that's why this sample is not very useful. There are definitely use cases for it though. When there's no `q` and you need a `p` from inside the class.

Comment: @DanM. yes you can do that because p and q are both shared_ptr. enable_shared_from_this is required when you are inside the class, e.g. in the method f() that I had above. It is a simplified example, but it shows the essentials

Comment: @ThorbjørnLindeijer, you are right, it's C++17 and later. Some implementations did follow the C++16 semantics before it was released. The proper handling for C++11 to C++14 should be to use `std::make_shared<T>`.

Comment: So is this basically the same as boost::intrusive_ptr ? What is the difference ?

Comment: ^ all the complications listed above, are reasons to not use these smart pointers. If the solution is more complex than the problem, what's the point? Sometimes these smart pointers simplify the code over new/delete, but sometimes they over complicate it. It makes training harder, understanding code harder, code bulkier, all things that increase chance of bugs (or increase maintenance costs) on a large code base). Just call 'new' in your Add(), and 'delete' in your Remove() and destructor, it was never that hard in the first place.

Answer (score 292):

from Dr Dobbs article on weak pointers, I think this example is easier to understand (source: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184402026):

...code like this won't work correctly:

```
int *ip = new int;
shared_ptr<int> sp1(ip);
shared_ptr<int> sp2(ip);
```

Neither of the two `shared_ptr` objects knows about the other, so both will try to release the resource when they are destroyed. That usually leads to problems.

Similarly, if a member function needs a `shared_ptr` object that owns the object that it's being called on, it can't just create an object on the fly:

```
struct S
{
  shared_ptr<S> dangerous()
  {
     return shared_ptr<S>(this);   // don't do this!
  }
};

int main()
{
   shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);
   shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1->dangerous();
   return 0;
}
```

This code has the same problem as the earlier example, although in a more subtle form. When it is constructed, the `shared_pt`r object `sp1` owns the newly allocated resource. The code inside the member function `S::dangerous` doesn't know about that `shared_ptr` object, so the `shared_ptr` object that it returns is distinct from `sp1`. Copying the new `shared_ptr` object to `sp2` doesn't help; when `sp2` goes out of scope, it will release the resource, and when `sp1` goes out of scope, it will release the resource again.

The way to avoid this problem is to use the class template `enable_shared_from_this`. The template takes one template type argument, which is the name of the class that defines the managed resource. That class must, in turn, be derived publicly from the template; like this:

```
struct S : enable_shared_from_this<S>
{
  shared_ptr<S> not_dangerous()
  {
    return shared_from_this();
  }
};

int main()
{
   shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);
   shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1->not_dangerous();
   return 0;
}
```

When you do this, keep in mind that the object on which you call `shared_from_this` must be owned by a `shared_ptr` object. This won't work:

```
int main()
{
   S *p = new S;
   shared_ptr<S> sp2 = p->not_dangerous();     // don't do this
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this illustrates the problem being solved better than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: +1: Good answer. As an aside, instead of `shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);` it may be preferred to use `shared_ptr<S> sp1 = make_shared<S>();`, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301511/stdshared-ptr-initialization-make-sharedfoo-vs-shared-ptrtnew-foo

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last line should read `shared_ptr<S> sp2 = p->not_dangerous();` because the pitfall here is that you **must create a shared_ptr the normal way before you call `shared_from_this()` the first time!** This is really easy to get wrong! Before C++17 it is **UB** to call `shared_from_this()` before exactly one shared_ptr has been created the normal way: `auto sptr = std::make_shared<S>();` or `shared_ptr<S> sptr(new S());`. Thankfully from C++17 onwards doing so will throw.

Comment: BAD Example: `S* s = new S();   shared_ptr<S> ptr = s->not_dangerous();` <-- [It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr<T>. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17).](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this). So the reality is that it should be called `always_dangerous()`, because you need the knowledge of if it has been shared already or not.

Comment: @AnorZaken Good point. It would've been useful if you had submitted an edit request to make that fix. I've just done so. The other useful thing would've been for the poster not to choose subjective, context-sensitive  method names!

Comment: Thanks, this explains the technique well, but still don't quite understand why we need this in real sceanrio, do you have a actual example?

Comment: This answer, as well as the accepted one, fails to provide a real-life example. The convoluted `shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1->not_dangerous();` can be simply replaced with `shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1;`.

Answer (score 39):

Here's my explanation, from a nuts and bolts perspective (top answer didn't 'click' with me). *Note that this is the result of investigating the source for shared_ptr and enable_shared_from_this that comes with Visual Studio 2012. Perhaps other compilers implement enable_shared_from_this differently...*

`enable_shared_from_this<T>` adds a private `weak_ptr<T>` instance to `T` which holds the '**one true reference count**' for the instance of `T`.

So, when you first create a `shared_ptr<T>` onto a new T*, that T*'s internal weak_ptr gets initialized with a refcount of 1. The new `shared_ptr` basically backs onto this `weak_ptr`.

`T` can then, in its methods, call `shared_from_this` to obtain an instance of `shared_ptr<T>` that **backs onto the same internally stored reference count**. This way, you always have one place where `T*`'s ref-count is stored rather than having multiple `shared_ptr` instances that don't know about each other, and each think they are the `shared_ptr` that is in charge of ref-counting `T` and deleting it when their ref-count reaches zero.

Comment: This is correct, and the really important part is `So, when you first create...` because that is a **requirement** (as you say the weak_ptr isn't initialized until you pass the objects pointer into a shared_ptr ctor!) and this requirement is where things can go horribly wrong if you are not careful. If you create no shared_ptr before calling `shared_from_this` you get UB - likewise if you create more than one shared_ptr you get UB too. You have to somehow make sure you create a shared_ptr _exactly_ once.

Comment: In other words the whole idea of `enable_shared_from_this`is brittle to begin with since the point is to be able to get a `shared_ptr<T>` from a `T*`, but in reality when you get a pointer `T* t` it is generally not safe to assume anything about it already being shared or not, and making the wrong guess is UB.

Comment: "_internal weak_ptr gets initialized with a refcount of 1_" weak ptr to T are non owning smart ptr to T. A weak ptr is a owning smart ref to enough information to make a owning ptr that is a "copy" of other owning ptr. A weak ptr has no ref count. It has access to a ref count, like all owning ref.

Answer (score 23):

There is one particular case where I find `enable_shared_from_this` extremely useful: Thread safety when using asynchronous callback.

Imagine class `Client` has a member of type `AsynchronousPeriodicTimer`:

```
struct AsynchronousPeriodicTimer
{
    // call this periodically on some thread...
    void SetCallback(std::function<void(void)> callback); 
    void ClearCallback(); // clears the callback
}

struct Client
{
    Client(std::shared_ptr< AsynchronousPeriodicTimer> timer) 
        : _timer(timer)

    {
        _timer->SetCallback(
            [this]
            () 
            {
                assert(this); // what if 'this' is already dead because ~Client() has been called?
                std::cout << ++_counter << '\n';
            }
            );
    }
    ~Client()
    {
        // clearing the callback is not in sync with the timer, and can actually occur while the callback code is running
        _timer->ClearCallback();
    }
    int _counter = 0;
    std::shared_ptr< AsynchronousPeriodicTimer> _timer;
}

int main()
{
    auto timer = std::make_shared<AsynchronousPeriodicTimer>();
    {
        auto client = std::make_shared<Client>(timer);
        // .. some code    
        // client dies here, there is a race between the client callback and the client destructor           
    }
}
```

The client class subscribes a callback function to the periodic timer. Once the client object goes out of scope, there is a race condition between the client's callback and the client's destructor. The callback may be invoked with a dangling pointer!

The solution: using `enable_shared_from_this` to extend the object lifetime for the duration of the callback invocation.

```
struct Client : std::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
{
Client(std::shared_ptr< AsynchronousPeriodicTimer> timer) 
    : _timer(timer)

    {

    }

    void Init()
    {
        auto captured_self = weak_from_this(); // weak_ptr to avoid cyclic references with shared_ptr

        _timer->SetCallback(
        [captured_self]
        () 
        {
            if (auto self = captured_self.lock())
            {
                // 'this' is guaranteed to be non-nullptr. we managed to promote captured_self to a shared_ptr           
                std::cout << ++self->_counter << '\n';
            }

        }
        );
    }
    ~Client()
    {
        // the destructor cannot be called while the callback is running. shared_ptr guarantees this
        _timer->ClearCallback();
    
    }
    int _counter = 0;
    std::shared_ptr< AsynchronousPeriodicTimer> _timer;
}
```

The mechanism of `enable_shared_from_this`, combined with the inherent thread safety of `std::shared_ptr` reference counting, enable us to ensure that the `Client` object cannot be destructed while the callback code is accessing its internal members.

Note that the `Init` method is separated from the constructor since the initialization process of `enable_shared_from_this` is not finalized until the constructor exits. Hence the extra method. It is generally unsafe to subscribe an asynchronous callback from within a constructor since the callback may access uninitialized fields.

Comment: In this specific example, I don't understand what is the added value of using enable_shared_from_this here, since the Client clears the timer callback in its destructor ?

Comment: @Scylardor imagine that during the time the timer callback is running, the desturctor is invoked in the main thread. The callback may be access destroyed 'this'. The actual clearing of the callback is neither atomic nor in sync with the timer.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for clearing that up. I forgot the multithreading implications of this. It makes sense now. Great example !

Comment: I would vote this as the best answer. It clearly addresses the question: WHY is enable_shared_from_this useful? Other answers only try to explain what enable_shared_from_this does.

Comment: @cyb70289 note that I just fixed a small mistake. Glad it helped.

Comment: In this example,is it really useful to capture the client’s weak_ptr? Weak_ptr will not increase the reference count. I think the client’s destructor will still be called before the scope disappears.

Comment: @clay you only need to extend the lifetime of the client object while the callback is accessing its internal fields. If you capture a shared_ptr, you will extend the client lifetime for the duration of the callback subscription. Also, you will create a cyclic reference which shared_ptr cannot handle.

Answer (score 5):

It's exactly the same in c++11 and later: It is to enable the ability to return `this` as a shared pointer since `this` gives you a raw pointer.

in other word, it allows you to turn code like this

```
class Node {
public:
    Node* getParent const() {
        if (m_parent) {
            return m_parent;
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }

private:

    Node * m_parent = nullptr;
};
```

into this:

```
class Node : std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Node> getParent const() {
        std::shared_ptr<Node> parent = m_parent.lock();
        if (parent) {
            return parent;
        } else {
            return shared_from_this();
        }
    }

private:

    std::weak_ptr<Node> m_parent;
};
```

Comment: This will only work if these objects are always managed by a `shared_ptr`. You might want to change the interface to make sure it's the case.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @curiousguy. This goes without saying. I also like typedef-ing all of my shared_ptr to improve readability when defining my public APIs. For example, instead of `std::shared_ptr<Node> getParent const()`, I would normally expose it as `NodePtr getParent const()` instead. If you absolutely need access to the internal raw pointer (best example: dealing with a C library), there's `std::shared_ptr<T>::get` for that, which I hate mentioning because I've this raw pointer accessor used too many times for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 4):

Note that using a boost::intrusive_ptr does not suffer from this problem.
This is often a more convenient way to get around this issue.

Comment: Yes, but `enable_shared_from_this` allows you to work with an API which specifically accepts `shared_ptr<>`. In my opinion, such an API is usually *Doing It Wrong* (as it's better to let something higher in the stack own the memory) but if you're forced to work with such an API, this is a good option.

Comment: Better to stay within the standard as much as you can.