# Flushing all asynchronous handlers in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm running some tests that need asynchronous communication, and the underlying framework is Asio.  Sometimes, a handler is kept in the processing loop even if the test has been tore down, for good reasons.  But then, it is called *after* the targets are deleted.

The `Test` class:

```
virtual void SetUp()
{
  _client = new Client;
  _server = new Server;

  Service::run();
}

virtual void TearDown()
{
  Service::stop();

  delete _client;
  delete _server;
}
```

The `Service` class:

```
static void run()
{
  _thread = new asio::thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, _service));
}

static void stop()
{
  _service->stop();

  _thread->join();
  delete _thread;

  _service->reset();
}
```

`io_service::stop()` is non-blocking so it gets quite useless in my case. If I delete the `io_service` object at the end of the function, the handler won't be called, but I'd like a better solution to force completion *before* the objects are deleted.

Note: the actual processing loop is done in a second thread, but it is joined in a `io_service::stop()` wrapper, and the whole problem doesn't seem to be thread-related.

I'm using Asio (non-Boost) 1.4.5, but could consider upgrading (to get the `io_service::stopped()` operation?).

EDIT: Add the `io_service` wrapper code as it seems to be relevant according to the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to me you need to re-think your design slightly. `io_service::stop` is indeed asynchronous, as you've noticed. It causes any invocations of `io_service::run()` to return as soon as possible. Any outstanding handlers are not invoked with `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` until the `~io_service()` destructor runs. To manage object lifetimes, you should use a `shared_ptr` as the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) suggests:

> The destruction sequence described
>   above permits programs to simplify
>   their resource management by using
>   shared_ptr<>. Where an object's
>   lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a
>   connection (or some other sequence of
>   asynchronous operations), a shared_ptr
>   to the object would be bound into the
>   handlers for all asynchronous
>   operations associated with it. This
>   works as follows:
>
> - When a single connection ends, all associated asynchronous operations
>     complete. The corresponding handler
>     objects are destroyed, and all
>     shared_ptr references to the objects
>     are destroyed.
> - To shut down the whole program, the io_service function stop() is called
>     to terminate any run() calls as soon
>     as possible. The io_service destructor
>     defined above destroys all handlers,
>     causing all shared_ptr references to
>     all connection objects to be
>     destroyed.

More specifically, you have a race condition

```
virtual void TearDown()
{
  service->stop();

  // ok, io_service is no longer running
  // what if outstanding handlers use _client or _server ??

  delete _client;
  delete _server;

  // now you have undefined behavior due to a dangling pointer
}
```

Comment: I cannot accept the next test to start before all the handlers have completed. And I could miss something if I destroy the `io_service` manually. I've updated the code: `_thread->join()` should make sure all the handlers are called, so I really don't see how I could get a race condition here.

Comment: @Warren how does joining the thread prevent a race condition? Your thread invokes `io_service::run`, which will return after `io_service::stop`. The handlers can still be outstanding at that point, which is why I posted the `~io_service` destructor documentation and its suggestion to manage object lifetime with `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using boost::shared_ptr to manage the object lifetimes? In some cases boost::enable_shared_from_this can be useful. An SO discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this).

Another option could be to join the thread after you call stop to make sure that the handlers have been called before deleting the objects.

Comment: This is getting quite specific to my environment, but the `shared_ptr` idea won't help here: the objects will still exists after the test is over, causing terrible side effects to the next tests.

The only object which is allowed to survive the tests is the `service`, because it is also used internally to manage timeouts and stuff. Maybe that's not a good practice.

Comment: Your second idea is already implemented, but doesn't seem to help either (maybe there's something to investigate here too).

Comment: Ok, weird, I would have thought that if you join the thread before deleting the objects would work since join blocks. Handlers should be called from the thread running io_service::run, and therefore no handlers can/should be called after.

Comment: This is the expected behavior, there might be something wrong elsewhere.