# c++ tr1 enable_shared_from_this what's the advantage?

Tags: c++, tr1

I am currently reading through C++ TR1 extensions and started focussing on std::tr1::shared_ptr.

So, I read so far that I can declare and initialize shared_ptr<> with this code:

```
class foo {};
std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> fsp(new foo);
std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> fps2(fsp);    // (1) init using first sp
```

Now I read about enable_shared_from_this ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982611%28v=VS.90%29.aspx ) and see this example:

```
class foo : public enable_shared_from_this<foo> {};
std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> fsp(new foo);
std::tr1::shared_ptr<foo> fps2 = fsp->shared_from_this(); // (2) init using first sp
```

My question is, why would I want to use shared_from_this in comparison to the initalization I labeled as "(1) init using first sp".

I have read the article [What is the usefulness of `enable_shared_from_this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this) and now better understand the usefulness of it.

But that leaves me open whether my "(1) init using first sp" is ok or what downsides I could face using it.

Comment: Can you trim your question down to ... your actual question? It's good that you learned something today, but that's not pertinent to the question.

Comment: I think due to the lack of experience with shared_ptr, each answered question uncovers the next. K-Ballo's answer confirms that (1) is actually ok.
Andy T's answer immediately answers the question that than popped up in my mind (where would I need enable_shared_from_this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enable_shared_from_this` is most useful in class implementation whose objects will be shared. You want to share the same reference counter for all instances of `shared_ptr`s of your object (is usually done by copying `shared_ptr`), but class implementation doesn't have any to make a copy. In this case you can use `shared_from_this`.

Consider:

```
struct A;

void f(shared_ptr<A> const&) {...}

struct A: public enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
    void a_f()
    {
        // you need to call f() here passing itself as a parameter
        f(shared_from_this());
    }
};

shared_ptr<A> a_ptr(new A());
a_ptr->a_f(); // in inner call to f() will be used temporary shared_ptr<A> 
// that uses (shares) the same reference counter as a_ptr
```

Comment: +1 2nd sentence is about as clear as you can get it explained: `You want to share [...] by copying shared_ptr, but [...] implementation doesn't have any to make a copy from`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the real need of the enable_shared_from_this. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK your statement (1) is ok. `enable_shared_from_this` is about getting a `shared_ptr` from the object, if you do have the `shared_ptr` already then you don't need to call it.