# incomplete type error on using boost::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

At the following line

`class Symbol : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Symbol> {`

I get the error:

error: invalid use of incomplete type `struct boost::enable_shared_from_this<Symbol>`
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:63: error: declaration of `struct boost::enable_shared_from_this<Symbol>`

Any idea why am I getting this error. Symbol is an abstract class(if that matters)

Comment: I want to pass a shared_ptr to `this` to functions that take boost::shared_ptr<Symbol> . I used the idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Er, it's *specifically* designed to be a base class.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Oops -- quite right. I guess I should have looked before I jumped in...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Opps. The error was because I did not include the header which *defines* enable_shared_from_this 
(which is boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp) .

It was only *declared* in /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp