# why am i getting this runtime exception when using shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In the following code, I am getting the following runtime exception (possibly memory leak) after return 1; and in destructor of Node().

`Unhandled exception at 0x0f9bad4a (msvcp100d.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefef2.`

It's been a while since I used smart_ptr, so am trying to learn what am I doing wrong here ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node;
typedef shared_ptr<Node> SharedNode;

class Node {
    Node* parent;
    vector< SharedNode > children;
    int value;

    //limiting construction
    Node(int a_value):value(a_value),parent(0){}
    Node(const Node &copy); //non-construction-copyable
    Node& operator=(const Node& copy); //non-copyable
public:
    static SharedNode create(int a_value){
        return SharedNode(new Node(a_value));
    }
    SharedNode addChild(SharedNode child){
        child->parent = this;
        children.push_back(child);
        return child;
    }

SharedNode getNode(int searchValue);
};

SharedNode Node::getNode(int searchValue){

    // Breadth First Search
    queue<SharedNode> que;
    que.push(SharedNode(this));

    while(!que.empty()){
        SharedNode node = que.front();
        que.pop();

        if(node->value == searchValue)
            return node;

        vector<SharedNode>::iterator it;
        for(it = node->children.begin(); it != node->children.end(); it++){
            que.push(*it);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(){
    SharedNode node_ptr = Node::create(5);

    for(int i  = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        node_ptr->addChild(Node::create(i));

    cout << (node_ptr->getNode(-1) != 0 ? "Found" : "Not found");

    return 1;
}
```

I think I'm messing up when I use shared_ptr on this, like: `shared_ptr(this)`. But then, that's my guess.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You got a double delete, that what the `0xfeeefef2` indicates. It's only a few bytes off of `0xfeeefeee`, which is the Windows debug heap's "memory freed" pattern. And yes, the problem is with constructing a `shared_ptr` from `this`. `shared_ptr` assumes ownership, but when `this` exists, something else already has ownership. Rethink your design.

Comment: I have a feeling `que.push(SharedNode(this));` is the culprit in `getNode()` function.

Comment: Why would you need shared semantics when you build a structure with a single parent? That makes no apparent sense to me. Everything here can be controlled by scope.

Comment: @pmr can you elaborate on that please ?

Comment: @brainydexter You are building a tree with back references from a child. The lifetime of everything depends on the root. There simply is no shared data here: only ownership and observers. A parent owns children and a child observes its parent. When a parent is deleted all it's children with it. But you probably have a use-case somewhere, e.g. children out-living a parent, but there can be nicer solutions.

Comment: @Xeo : What do you mean by this: `shared_ptr assumes ownership, but when this exists, something else already has ownership.`

Comment: To have a `this` pointer, the object needs to exist already, and something has ownership on it (the scope, something else, whatever). `shared_ptr` assumes that it gets the sole ownership of whatever you pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is from

`que.push(SharedNode(this));`

This creates a new shared pointer that now owns `this`.  However, due to the `create()` method, there is another shared pointer that owns the same object.  This can result in a double delete.

If you have a reason to use a shared pointer in this situation, the correct solution is `enable_shared_from_this`.

First, change the node definition to this.

`class Node : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node> { ...`

Then change the offending line to

`que.push(this->shared_from_this());`

This causes it to return a shared_ptr that points to the object, but it is shared with the already existing shared_ptr, instead of being two separate shared_ptr objects.

Note, for the use of `this->shared_from_this()` to be legal, the object must be owned by a shared_ptr.  You already have accomplished this via the static `create()` method, but I wanted to make sure you understood the limitation.

Edit:  A brief explanation of `shared_ptr` ownership.

When you create a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer using the constructor, it creates a reference object that contains both a pointer to the object and a reference count, which is used to determine how many `shared_ptr` objects point to it.  A pointer to this reference object is then passed to all copies that are made from that original `shared_ptr`, with the reference count keeping track of how many `shared_ptr` objects refer to it.

When you call `shared_ptr(this)`, there is no way for the shared pointer to know that `this` is owned by another shared pointer, and creates a new reference object. Once the one of them reaches a reference count of zero, the object will be deleted, despite the other `shared_ptr` reference object still pointing to it, resulting in a dangling pointer and the error you are seeing.

If you only need the children to exist when the parent exists, I would consider changing the Node to simply have a `std::vector` of other Nodes (remove the pointer).  When the highest level node is destroyed via its destructor, it will destroy the vector, which destroys the children nodes, and so-on.

```
class Node
{
  // whatever operations you need... 

  std::vector<Node> children;
}
```

Edit: As requested...

If you have a use case where you do really want to have the children outlive the parents, you'll have to deal with the parent pointer, since it could be destroyed before the children.  One quick solution is determine if you really NEED the parent pointer, and eliminate it if you don't need it.

However, assuming you still want to retain it, you cannot use `shared_ptr` here.  If you do that, you'll have a circular dependency, and neither will be destroyed automatically, which isn't what you want.

The solution here is to use `std::weak_ptr`.  Basically, it interacts with the `shared_ptr` reference object in such a way that it doesn't prevent the destruction of the pointed to object.

```
class Node
{
private:
   std::weak_ptr<Node> parent;
   // Other constructors.  
   Node(int a_value):value(a_value),parent() {} 
public:
   SharedNode addChild(SharedNode child){
        child->parent = this->shared_from_this(); // Initialize their pointer using
                                                  // your shared pointer
        children.push_back(child);
        return child;
   }
   // This function will return a shared_ptr to nullptr (and will evaluate false) 
   // if you have no parent, or if the parent node has been deleted
   SharedNode getParent()
   {
       return parent.lock();
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Dave! That was very easy to follow and understand. Since I have no public constructors and `create()` is the only way to construct objects in this case, this->shared_from_this() for any object will always be legal. Am I correct in understanding that ?

Comment: @brainydexter: I would like to add some weight to pmr's comment above.  Do you have a use case to have the child nodes outlive the parent?  If not, there are easier ways to accomplish this.  And if you do, you'll want to do something about the parent pointer, which could be left dangling if the parent object is destroyed.  To solve the latter problem, I suggest you look at `std::weak_ptr`

Comment: Thanks! This is a related doubt: in this code: `shared_ptr<Node> smart1 = new Node;
shared_ptr<Node> smart2 = smart1;` (see Mark's reply). reference counter to pointer held in smart1 will be increased to 2 ? If so, when I do something like shared_ptr(this) in this given situation, shouldn't the reference increase to two ?

Comment: :) I'm still scratching my head about weak_ptr since I read them thrice and couldn't really understand. I guess a use case of where to use weak_ptr might help. As for pmr's comment, children would only exist only as long as parent would exist. What would be an easier way of dealing with this ?

Comment: Dave, thanks a ton for the elaborate answer and I think I understand shared_ptr, better than ever before! I've marked your answer as the answer. If its not too much to ask for, can you also cite in here how to use `weak_ptr` to solve the `other` case, where if, child nodes outlive the parent. Once again, thanks a ton!

Comment: Also came across this gem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this

Answer (score 4):

Consider what happens with the following code:

```
Node * dumb_ptr = new Node;
shared_ptr<Node> smart1 = dumb_ptr;
shared_ptr<Node> smart2 = dumb_ptr;
```

You now have two smart pointers both thinking they own the same object. One of them is going to delete the object, and the other one will try to use or delete that deleted object at some point. The way you fix this is by always creating a smart pointer from another smart pointer or from `new`. Best to never use any dumb pointers at all - that includes `this`.

```
shared_ptr<Node> smart1 = new Node;
shared_ptr<Node> smart2 = smart1;
```

Comment: I understand the problem with both smart pointers thinking they own the same object which causes trouble later on. Just to be sure, when we create a shared pointer from another pointer, the reference counter increases ?

Comment: Also, in this case, I cannot change the signature of getNode() function and I have to return a SharedNode. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: @brainydexter, you need to find a way to get an existing SharedNode to make a copy from. I don't know how you'd do it offhand, except maybe to look through all the SharedNodes contained in the parent.

Comment: See Dave's answer. `enable_shared_from_this` did it for me. However, I'd still like to understand one more thing. When something like this happens: `shared_ptr<Node> smart2 = smart1;`; the reference counter to the pointer held in smart1 is increased to 2, correct ?

Comment: @brainydexter, yes the counter will be incremented to account for the new pointer. The counter itself won't be contained within the smart pointer, since it might need to continue to live after the first smart pointer has been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the explanation!