# How to return a shared_ptr of this to the object that owns it?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

The similar questions here all seem to use boost, which I'm not using.

What I'm trying to do is demonstrated by the following:

In the "owner":

```
std::shared_ptr<State> m_state;

m_state = make_shared<State>(param);

m_state = m_state->SomeVirtualFunction();    // The original m_state object gets destroyed
```

In the "owned":

```
std::shared_ptr<State> State::SomeVirtualFunction() {
    return std:shared_ptr<State>(this);
}
```

In Visual C++ in MSVS 2012, the owned object gets destroyed.  How can I keep it alive?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` came from boost, so the answers to the questions using boost will most likely be applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to inherit from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this); see [What is the usefulness of `enable_shared_from_this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this).  `std::enable_shared_from_this` equips your type with a member function `shared_from_this` that you call instead of `std::shared_ptr<State>(this)`:

```
std::shared_ptr<State> State::SomeVirtualFunction() {
    return shared_from_this();
}
```

Prior to C++11 (or Boost, which is where C++11 got `enable_shared_from_this` from), and assuming that you have a `shared_ptr` implementation that doesn't provide `enable_shared_from_this`, you can do this manually by giving `State` a `weak_ptr` to itself that it can convert to a `shared_ptr` when it needs to:

```
class State {
    ...
    std::weak_ptr<State> weak_self;
};

m_state = make_shared<State>(param);
m_state->weak_self = m_state;

std::shared_ptr<State> State::SomeVirtualFunction() {
    return weak_self.lock()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`State` should inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<State>` and `State::SomeVirtualFunction()` should be

```
return shared_from_this();
```

Note that you must not change the code in the owner.