# How to assign in c++ an object created in python?

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python, make-shared

I've basically have a very simple node test case I'm trying to fix.

I have a simple Node class with a getChild and a getParent

The child can be assigned via the addChild function

Then this function **automatically set the parent on the relevant class (so from the c++ side)**

Unfortunately when I do that I **lose the python reference..**

I guess the code should be better to understand :

the **basic main class MyNode**:

```
class MyNode
{
public:
    MyNode(): m_name("unknown") {}
    MyNode(std::string name): m_name(name) {}
    MyNode(MyNode * const o) : m_name(o->m_name) {}
    virtual ~MyNode() {}

    std::string getName() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(std::string name) { m_name = name; }
    boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> getChild() const { return m_child; }
    const boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> & getParent() const { return m_parent; }

    void addChild(boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> node) {
        m_child = node;
        node->m_parent = boost::make_shared<MyNode>(this);
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
    boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> m_parent;
    boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> m_child;
};
```

Then the **boost python bindings code** :

```
class_< MyNode, boost::shared_ptr<MyNode>/*, MyNodeWrapper*/ >("MyNode", init<std::string>())
    .add_property( "Name", &MyNode::getName, &MyNode::setName )
    .add_property( "Child", &MyNode::getChild )
    .add_property( "Parent", make_function(&MyNode::getParent, return_internal_reference<>()))
    .def( "addChild", &MyNode::addChild )
    ;
```

To finish **my python test code** :

```
>>> p=MyNode("p")
>>> o=MyNode("o")
>>> p.addChild(o)
>>> o.Parent
<hello_ext.MyNode object at 0x01C055A8>   << this is not equal to p
>>> p
<hello_ext.MyNode object at 0x01C06510>   << as you can see p here
>>> o.Parent
<hello_ext.MyNode object at 0x01C055A8>   << but at least the pointer doesn't change each time the Parent is called !
>>> p.Child == o                          << so for the child it works
True
>>> o.Parent == p                         << but it doeesn't work for Parent
False
```

The issue is certainly in the addFunction and how I use boost::make_shared to set the parent.
I unfortunately have no idea what's going on..
I've tried to use a boost wrapper:

```
struct MyNodeWrapper : public MyNode, public boost::python::wrapper<MyNode>
{
    MyNodeWrapper( PyObject * a_PyObj ) : m_Self( a_PyObj ) {}
    MyNodeWrapper( PyObject * a_PyObj, const MyNode & a_Vec ) : MyNode( a_Vec ), m_Self( a_PyObj ) {}
    MyNodeWrapper( PyObject * a_PyObj, std::string name ) : MyNode( name ) , m_Self( a_PyObj ) {}

    PyObject * m_Self;
};
```

But still I'm not sure how I should modify the addChild function

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
    node->m_parent = boost::make_shared<MyNode>(this);
```

Without `boost::enable_shared_from_this`.  See [What is the usefulness of `enable_shared_from_this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this)

Comment: Thank you so much !

I found another solution where I was using an external function.. something like this :

`void addChild(boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> pythis, boost::shared_ptr<MyNode> node) 
{
 pythis->m_child = node;
 node->m_parent = pythis; 
}`

Comment: but your solution is way better.. so in case someone else has the same issue all you have to do is inherit from enable_shared_from_this then the addFunction can assign the parent pointer like that: node->m_parent = shared_from_this();

too easy and thanks again !