# Why we need enabled_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am looking into the boost documentation for shared_ptr and enable_shared_from_this and I can not figure out practical use of enable_shared_from_this.

Below is my understanding of enable_shared_from_this (example copied from [What is the usefulness of `enable_shared_from_this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this)).

```
class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
    public:
      Y(): count(3){}
      shared_ptr<Y> f()
      {
         return shared_from_this();
      }
      int count;
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q = p->f();
    cout << "\n Count from P is " << p1->count;
    cout << "\n Count from q is " << q1->count;
}
```

So, now we have a shared pointer q which points to the same object owned by p (new Y) and the object gets destroyed when both p and q go out of scope. And both the print statements above will print 3 as the count.

Now, I can achieve the same thing without the use of enable_shared_from_this by doing below.

```
class Y
{
    public:
      Y(): count(3){}
      int count;
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q(p);
    cout << "\n Count from P is " << p1->count;
    cout << "\n Count from q is " << q1->count;
}
```

Even in the above example both P and Q point to the same object and will print 3.

So, what benefit am I getting by using the enable_shared_from_this?

Comment: You didn't get the mention of `count` right in the sample you're pointing to. The answerer meant the internal `shared_ptr` count.

Comment: A crazy thought: `shared_from_this` is some kind of "adult version" of old C++ code that uses `delete this`; i.e. it appeals to the same dirty minds.

Comment: @g-makulik - I believe my question is different to the previous question already asked in SO. My question is that both examples above provide shared ownership to the object Y. In that case, why should we use enable_shared_from_this? what benefit is enable_shared_from_this providing compared to 2nd example?

Comment: @devana It's very well explained there why it's needed and useful, and I don't see your question adding any value above the other one. It's not just rewording and changing the samples slightly, that make up a new question.

Comment: @KerrekSB hat-tip https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/519773714003402752

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`shared_from_this` is a very special animal. Usually, you should *separate responsibilities*: A class does one thing, and one thing only. Owning a resource is such a responsibility, so a class should either own a resource and do nothing else, or do something else but not own a resource.

The use for `shared_from_this` is when this principle is violated, and a class *knows* that it is owned by a shared pointer. In that case, you need a way to get at that ambient shared pointer that is owning you. You cannot simply say `shared_ptr<T>(this)`, because that would create a *new* owner, rather than share ownership with the existing owner.

To communicate from the class to its ambient owner, you need to derive from `enable_shared_from_this`, and then use `shared_from_this` to produce a new shareholder.

(This works practically by adding a `weak_ptr<T>` member to the class, and upon creation of the ambient shared pointer, that weak pointer is set to observe the shared pointer. So `shared_from_this` is a simple `lock()` invocation on the weak pointer.)

---

Here's an example to clarify the usage:

```
auto x = std::make_shared<T>();
f(*x);

// ...

void f(T const & t)
{
    auto y = t.shared_from_this();
    // ...
}
```

Inside `f`, we don't see the owner of `t` immediately, but `shared_from_this` brings it out.

Comment: My understanding is that 2nd example provided the question gives the same shared ownership as provided by enable_shared_from_this in the 1st example. Am I correct in thinking in that? If both the examples provide shared ownership to the object, why should i use enable_shared_from_this ?

Comment: @devana: Of course, but in the second example you're cheating and you already have `p`. `shared_from_this` is for situations where you only have `*p` (or `p->`)! I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for that 2nd example. That makes it very clear.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your objection?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is a matter of structuring. In your example, the guy who owns `q` might not know anything about, or have access to, the guy who owns `p`. It's sometimes easier to get another `shared_ptr` to the same instance from the type (in this case `Y`).

That said, I personally *never* use `enable_shared_from_this`. It's in the same boat as singletons as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: `shared_from_this` is an important idiom, when creating anonymous functors bound to `this` and passing them to an asynchronous subsystem, for instance.