# How useful is std::enable_shared_from_this if you already have a std::shared_ptr at your disposal?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

I have stumbled on std::enable_shared_from_this, notably on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this), but I still don't understand what is the point

The recurring example is the following :

```
class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
    public:

    shared_ptr<Y> f()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q = p->f();
}
```

But I don't get this example, if I were in this situation I would just do :

```
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q = p; // Results in exactly the same thing
}
```

Thanks

Edit : I think the person who closed the question did not understand my intent. The post is marked as duplicate of another post, while **the very first line** of this post links to that very same "other post". I have a question which the so-called duplicate has no answer for.

To be specific, a class implementing enable_shared_from_this needs to be created as a std::shared_ptr. So you have access to that shared_ptr. My question was (in the title mind you), "Because you are forced to have a std::shared_ptr anyways, does keeping track of it actually renders std::enable_shared_from_this useless/redundant?"

Comment: That's all well and good when you have `p`. What if you're inside of `Y` and need to pass a `shared_ptr` to `this` to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two use cases immediately spring to mind:

1. It allows the object to hand itself off to something else that then keeps a shared pointer.  The object itself doesn't own a shared copy.  The point of `shared_from_this` is to give the object an internal `weak_ptr`.
2. Since passing shared pointers around is expensive (and redundant, when you know it's always owned within a call stack), it is standard practice to pass around the contained object as a reference.  If, somewhere down the call stack, you need to obtain the shared pointer again, you can do so via `shared_from_this`.

Comment: Good answer and UV'ed, I think it's worth mentioning that in *most* cases it's better to avoid these tools. For instance, calling a function by reference from your smart pointer'ed object generally guarantees that it will not have its ownership semantics messed with, `shared_from_this` basically throws that away. Of course, you may have a good reason to throw that away, but you should indeed require a good reason.