# Why do we use enable_shared_from_this template?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-ptr, std

Recently I have met the `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` template, which is the same as its [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) version.
So It describes the following sample code:

```
class Y: public enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
public:

    shared_ptr<Y> f()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q = p->f();
    assert(p == q);
    assert(!(p < q || q < p)); // p and q must share ownership
}
```

What is the reason  creating the shared_ptr through `f()?`
Whats wrong with `shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);`?

Comment: unnamed and invisible down voters, please consider putting a comment

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm not sure what your asking. You can use a new'd variable in a shared pointer. You need this instance method to get things sharing a refernce count: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this

Comment: This is a poor example since you could just use `auto q = p;`.

Comment: I understand, why cant the second shared_ptr be created using the first shared_ptr, without invoking shared from this.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan It can.

Comment: this example is from boost documentation @FrançoisAndrieux. I know that by that time auto was not introduced, but why cant we just create a shared ptr using the first one?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan You don't need `shared_from_this` here. `std::shared_ptr<Y> q = p;` is fine here. `shared_from_this` is only relevant when you need a `shared_ptr` to an instance that is already owned by a `shared_ptr` but you can't access a copy of that pointer directly.

Comment: One school of thought is that objects should not be self-aware that they are contained in a shared_ptr.  There are also caveats, such as UB or (C++17) exception if done incorrectly.  That being said, I find it helpful when porting from C#, because C++ shared_ptr has similar semantics to C# references.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thats all clear now! thx

Comment: @Eljay "_One school of thought is_" another "school" says that if an object is "self aware", it should be a good reason, because the design 
implies that, it should be an invariant of the class (let's call it `managed`), and then `shared_from_this` is fragile and insufficient, and you should provide a factory function to make the object (`make_managed`) and not allow the construction by `new` or an automatic or static object or a member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Whats wrong with shared_ptr p(new Y);?

There is nothing wrong with it, only issue you may not have it inside a member of class `Y` and sometimes you want a member to return `std::shared_ptr` to itself. `std::shared_ptr<Y>(  this )` is an obviously wrong way to create one.

I wonder if such example can make things clearer and would be still simple enough:

```
std::shared_ptr<Y> Y::getObject() 
{
     return some_condition ? shared_from_this() : std::make_shared<Y>( somedata );
}
```

Comment: thanks Slavik, that is exactly what I was asking!! You feel me this time ;)

Answer (score 3):

The point of `shared_from_this` is to allow you to get a `shared_ptr` when you *don't* already have access to one. It's pointless in your example because your example is too simplified. Imagine there's some function that only gets a `Y*` or a `Y&`, and it needs to share ownership with someone. This frequently happens for *members* of `Y`, since members only have access to `this`.