# Is it safe to use a boost::signals2::scoped_connection object as member of a class for automatic connection lifetime?

Tags: c++, boost-signals2

I wondered whether the following code is safe with respect to the fact that the signal might be triggered by a different thread:

```
using IntSignal = boost::signals2::signal<void(int)>;

class Foo
{
public:

  Foo(IntSignal& signal)
    : some_resource(new int(0))
  {
    scoped_connection = signal.connect([this](int i) { some_action(i); });
  }

  ~Foo()
  {
    delete some_resource;
  }

private:

  void some_action(int i)
  {
    *some_resource = i;
  }

  int* some_resource;

  boost::signals2::scoped_connection scoped_connection;
}
```

EDIT: added an imaginary resource, destructor and an implementation for `some_action` to make it more clear. With this question I would like to clarify whether my assumption is correct that the signal's slot might be called after `Foo`'s destructor but before `scoped_connection`'s destructor. I omitted a mutex protecting `some_resource` for brevity, however, it is not relevant for the question.

Although the connection will be dropped when a `Foo` instance is destroyed, there might be a tiny gap betwen `Foo`'s own destructor invocation and the destruction of `Foo`'s members. This might be even more problematic if resources are being used within `some_action` after they have been destructed.

Should I rather use normal connections and disconnect them in `Foo`'s destructor? And would it be safe to have the `scoped_connection` member as last member of the class (that should get destroyed first) and omit any destruction logic?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a test case that demonstrates the (possible) problem? Unless you're using the signal across threads I don't really understand the issue here.

Comment: I extended the example and added a note about it. Yes, the signal might be triggered by a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is a possible race if `Foo`'s destructor is invoked while the signal is running and accessing `some_resource`.

A safe solution would be to extend the life of `Foo` while the slots are running:

```
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
public:

  Foo(IntSignal& signal)
    : some_resource(new int(0))
  {        
      // moved connection initialization to a method since weak_from_this will  
      // be empty inside the constructor. It is initialized only afterwards.
      // It also make sense to connect your signal only after object
      // is fully initialized
  }

  void InitConnection()
  {
     auto weak_self = weak_from_this(); 
     scoped_connection = signal.connect(
       [weak_self](int i) 
      { 
         if (auto self = weak_self.lock())
         {
            // we managed to promote weak_self to a shared_ptr, 'this' will be alive 
            // as long as this scope lives
            some_action(i); // safe
         }
      });

  }

  ~Foo()
  {
     // will only be invoked after Foo's reference count drops to zero.
     // not during the signal is emitted
     delete some_resource; 
  }

private:    
  void some_action(int i)
  {
    *some_resource = i;
  }

  int* some_resource;    
  boost::signals2::scoped_connection scoped_connection;
}
```

Notes:

1. `enable_shared_from_this` initializes a `weak_ptr` to 'this'. It is a great tool for the situation you described. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this/63579750#63579750).
2. Make sure you create Foo as a **shared_ptr**, otherwise weak_from_this will not work.
   Remember: Foo is **shared** between 2 threads.