# How do you create a smart pointer from 'this'?

Tags: c++

In a non-const member function, I want to pass 'this' to a function, but the function takes a shared_ptr. When I try to pass it like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Piece>(this)
```

I get weird exceptions saying: "Chess.exe has triggered a breakpoint"

Am I converting from 'this' to shared_ptr in the wrong way?

Comment: [like that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: @pptaszni This would work only if `*this` is already managed by a shared pointer.

Comment: @Daniel Langr So how should I do this instead?

Comment: Yup, that's true, it needs to be managed by `shared_ptr` already. If it is not, can you show the full example of what you are trying to do. Maybe there is some design issue.

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: You can create a "non-owning" shared pointer with no-op deleter: `std::shared_ptr<Piece>(this, [](Piece*){});`. But I am not sure whether this is legal (definitely this does not correspond with how shared pointers are intended to be used).

Comment: Useful reading: [What is the usefulness of `enable_shared_from_this`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712279/what-is-the-usefulness-of-enable-shared-from-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using shared pointers to manage the object's memory then this is what `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` is for e.g.

```
#include <memory>

class Piece;

void takes_a_shared_piece(std::shared_ptr<Piece> ptr) {
    //do something
}

class Piece : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Piece> {
public:
    Piece(); 

    void do_something() {
        takes_a_shared_piece( shared_from_this() );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the above discussions revolve around using the std::enable_shared_from_this, you could do it the original way (C++11 style)by making `shared_ptr` work in tandem with `make_shared`. What your code needs is a call like `std::make_shared<Piece>(*this)` which invokes a non-const member function `int foo(std::shared_ptr<T>);`. Refer the code below:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct S {
    int foo(std::shared_ptr<T>);
};

class Piece {
    S<Piece> *s;
public:
    Piece () {
        s = new S<Piece>();
    }

    void call_S () {
        s->foo(std::make_shared<Piece>(*this));
    }
};

int main() {
    Piece *knight = new Piece();
    return 0;
}
```

Remember, you create a `shared_ptr` by `make_shared`. Refer to the overloads here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared