# c++ push_back copying object instead of reference

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, shared-ptr

I'm having some issues understanding a problem I've mentioned in the comments below:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node(int value): value(value), neighbors() {}
        int value;
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> neighbors;
};

    std::vector<Node> nodes;
    nodes.reserve(50);
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 50; ++j) {
        nodes.push_back(Node(j));
    }
    for(int j = 1 ; j < 25; ++j) {
        nodes.at(0).neighbors.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(nodes.at(j)));
    }

    //The following line is copying nodes.at(0) instead of just 
    //copying a reference to nodes.at(0). Why?
    nodes.at(15).neighbors.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(nodes.at(0)));

    for(int j = 25 ; j < 50; ++j) {
        nodes.at(0).neighbors.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(nodes.at(j)));
    }

    std::cout << nodes.at(15).neighbors.at(0).neighbors.size();
    //Prints out 24

    std::cout << nodes.at(0).neighbors.size();
    //Prints out 49
```

Why is the following line copying nodes.at(0) (which returns a reference to the first element of nodes vector) instead of storing a reference to it?

```
    nodes.at(15).neighbors.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(nodes.at(0)));
```

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to work. BTW: To make your question more precise, find out if `push_back` or `make_shared` actually copies your node.

Comment: *How* do you know it's copied? You are aware of that `std::make_shared<Node>` will create a `Node` instance, and invoke the new objects *copy-constructor* to initialize it using the node from `nodes.at(0)`? Is it that copy-construction you're talking about?

Comment: Do you know what `std::make_shared` does?

Comment: See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

`This function is typically used to replace the construction std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...))`

Comment: Is there a way to use shared pointers without invoking the copy constructor? My intention was to have the neighbors vector store pointers to objects but I did not want to go with storing raw pointers (std::vector<Node*>).

Comment: Note that if you're planning on adding any more nodes to `nodes` after this, you can't store pointers to the nodes at all! That's because `vector` is allowed to allocate new `Node`s, copy/move the old ones into the new ones, and then delete the old ones, and any pointers to the old ones become invalid at that point.

Comment: You'd need to make `nodes` store `shared_ptr`s too.

Comment: What you're doing is, roughly, equivalent to `Node new_node = nodes.at(0)`. The only way to not use the copy-constructor would be to use the *copy* assignment operator (e.g. `Node new_node; new_node = nodes.at(0)`). If you want to initialize one object with another of the same class, then the copy-constructor is invoked. That's how C++ works.

Comment: And here it makes no sense using a vector of share pointers, not the way you do it anyway with creating new object. The usual is to have a vector of *raw* pointers and have each of them point to the *actual* node in `nodes`. But as mentions by @immibis that won't work well if you ever resize `nodes`. A better solution would be `neighbors` to be a vector of *indexes* into the `nodes` vector.

Comment: Note that if your graph has cycles then even using `shared_ptr` needs some care, because if there are cycles the objects will never be deleted.  I n general you are better off storing the list of connections separate to the list of nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in your code stores references. Your code copies a node because you allocate a new node in `std::make_shared` and invoke the copy constructor.

```
  std::vector<Node> nodes;
```

It's local to your function. It would be impossible to keep either pointers (shared or not)  or references to elements of this vector. Perhaps you want to use a vector of shared pointers instead:

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
```

Bear in mind that shared_ptr doesn't work well in presence of cyclic referenced. If your data structure is a general graph, then perhaps shared_ptr is not appropriate for storing neighbours. You may want to consider weak_ptr instead (you will have to keep a container of shared pointers to all nodes separately).

Answer (score 1):

Vector always stores the copies. You can find more information here :
[Is std::vector copying the objects with a push_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275076/is-stdvector-copying-the-objects-with-a-push-back)

Comment: Not relevant in this case as the vector in question store `std::share_ptr` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
// The following line is copying nodes.at(0) instead of just 
nodes.at(15).neighbors.push_back(std::shared_ptr<Node>(&nodes.at(0))); 

// Notice I didn't call make_shared, because make_shared woul allocate anew Node,
// but you already have allocated your node in your nodes vector (which is global).

// 24 as expected
std::cout << nodes.at(0).neighbors.size() << std::endl;
// 24 as well
std::cout << nodes.at(15).neighbors.at(0)->neighbors.size() << std::endl;

//Insert another element
nodes.at(0).neighbors.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(nodes.at(30)));

// 25 as expected
std::cout << nodes.at(0).neighbors.size() << std::endl;
// 25 as well
std::cout << nodes.at(15).neighbors.at(0)->neighbors.size() << std::endl;
```

Let me know If I understood your issue correctly.

You could instead use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>`, and then just push

```
nodes.at(15).neighbors.push_back(nodes.at(0));
```

The other solution using a vector of shared ptr would be:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes;
nodes.reserve(50);

for (int j = 0; j < 50; ++j)
    nodes.push_back(std::make_shared<Node>(j));

for (int j = 1; j < 25; ++j)
    nodes.at(0)->neighbors.push_back(nodes.at(j));

nodes.at(15)->neighbors.push_back(nodes.at(0));

// 24 as expected
std::cout << nodes.at(0)->neighbors.size() << std::endl;
// 24 as well
std::cout << nodes.at(15)->neighbors.at(0)->neighbors.size() << std::endl;

//Insert another element
nodes.at(0)->neighbors.push_back(nodes.at(30));

// 25 as expected
std::cout << nodes.at(0)->neighbors.size() << std::endl;
// 25 as well
std::cout << nodes.at(15)->neighbors.at(0)->neighbors.size() << std::endl;
```