# USACO Cow Steeplechase: Dinic's Algorithm/Changes to Pointer Not Registering

Tags: c++, pointers, max-flow

***Disclaimer: Not all of the code I used to attempt to solve the problem is needed to answer my question, but I will provide the rest if it is needed.***

Problem (If Context is Needed): http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=93

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define INF 1000000000

struct Edge{
    int from, to, cap, flow;
    Edge* backwards;
    Edge(int a, int b, int c, int d): from(a), to(b), cap(c), flow(d) {}
};

struct Dinic{
    int n, source, sink, dist [1000];
    queue<int> q;
    vector<Edge> adjacency [1000];
    bool blocked [1000];
    Dinic(int x): n(x), source(n++), sink(n++) { }
    void add(int v1, int v2, int c, int f){
        Edge e(v1, v2, c, f); Edge r(v2, v1, 0, 0);
        e.backwards = &r; r.backwards = &e;
        adjacency[v1].push_back(e); adjacency[v2].push_back(r);
    }
    bool bfs(){
        q = queue<int>(); fill_n(dist, 1000, -1); dist[sink] = 0; q.push(sink);
        while(q.size() > 0){
            int node = q.front(); q.pop();
            if(node == source) return true;
            for(int i = 0; i < adjacency[node].size(); i++){
                if(adjacency[node][i].backwards->cap > adjacency[node][i].backwards->flow && dist[adjacency[node][i].to] == -1){
                    dist[adjacency[node][i].to] = dist[node]+1;
                    q.push(adjacency[node][i].to);
                }
            }
        }
        return dist[source] != -1;
    }
    int dfs(int pos, int mini){
        if(pos == sink) return mini;
        int flowy = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < adjacency[pos].size(); i++){
            int curr = 0;
            if(!blocked[adjacency[pos][i].to] && dist[adjacency[pos][i].to] == dist[pos]-1 && adjacency[pos][i].cap > adjacency[pos][i].flow){
                curr = dfs(adjacency[pos][i].to, min(mini-flowy, adjacency[pos][i].cap-adjacency[pos][i].flow));
                adjacency[pos][i].flow += curr; adjacency[pos][i].backwards->flow -= adjacency[pos][i].flow;
                flowy += curr;
            }
            if(flowy == mini) return flowy;
        }
        blocked[pos] = flowy != mini;
        return flowy;
    }
    int flow(){
        int ret = 0; fill_n(blocked, 1000, false);
        while(bfs()){
            fill_n(blocked, 1000, false);
            ret += dfs(source, INF);
            cout << ret << endl;
        }
        return ret;
    }
};
```

The problem essentially narrows down to finding the minimum number of vertices that make up the vertex cover of a bipartite graph. I was able to successfully construct said graph in the unseen part of my code, but my problem lies in running Dinic's algorithm on it.

I keep getting an infinite loop when I do so, which stems from an error in the "dfs()" method. Whenever I try to update a "backwards Edge" pointer, it does not maintain the change as intended, resulting in the same path being taken over and over again.

I am very new to using pointers, and I have not been able to find a solution or explanation for my pointer-related problem after hours of searching.

Please help, and thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added in a segment of code that displays the problem.

```
Dinic solve(3);
solve.add(0, 3, 1, 0);
solve.adjacency[3][0].backwards->flow = 1;
cout << solve.adjacency[0][0].flow << endl; //prints out 0 instead of 1
```

Comment: Do be careful to distinguish between updating a pointer and updating the object it points to.  You describe the problem as if it were the former, but never after first setting them do you even attempt to modify the `backwards` pointers themselves.

Comment: Odds are very good we would not want all of the code for context, but a simple test program that repeatably demonstrates the misbehaviour, a [mcve], is worth it's weight in gold. In fact by producing an MCVE you might find that you've answered your own question.

Comment: Your implementation is a bit odd.  Dinic's is an algorithm for *directed* graphs, but you seem to be building an *undirected* one, in the sense that you add a backward edge for each forward edge.  This may be part of your problem, and it is particularly likely to be part of the problem if your graph has any genuine two-edge loops.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have tested the implementation in Java (a language I am more familiar with that does not require explicit use of pointers), so I know that my problem is with the pointers. Can you elaborate on the difference between updating a pointer and updating the object it points to? I set the pointer that points to the object, so shouldn't both be updated? EDIT: Tested the implementation in C++ without explicitly using pointers, and it produces the desired result.

Comment: @user4581301 I added in the MCVE. Unfortunately, it didn't answer my own question, but hopefully it will better enable others to.

Comment: @YouKnowMe the value of a pointer is just an address.  Modifying a pointer means changing that address (the address itself, not the data located *at* the address).  That has no effect on the value of the old or new pointed-to thing itself, which could still be accessible through a different pointer or directly via a variable.  Java has close analogs of all of this, so it should not be novel to you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Could you please provide an example showing the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems highlighted by your example are in the `add()` method:

> ```
>     void add(int v1, int v2, int c, int f){
>         Edge e(v1, v2, c, f); Edge r(v2, v1, 0, 0);
>         e.backwards = &r; r.backwards = &e;
>         adjacency[v1].push_back(e); adjacency[v2].push_back(r);
>     }
> ```

Observe first that you are declaring the `Edge` instances designated by `e` and `r` on the stack, and therefore that their lifetime ends when the variables go out of scope at the end of the method.  This is indeed different from Java, in which objects can be allocated only on the heap, and you have only references to them.

In each `Edge` you set a pointer to the other stack-allocated `Edge`, but that pointer value is only useful for the lifetime of the pointed-to (stack-allocated) objects; dereferencing them later, i.e. after that method returns, produces undefined behavior.

Moreover, it is essential to understand that [`vector::push_back` *creates a copy* of its argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275095/2402272); in that sense it is unlike, say, Java's `List.add()`.  Those copies contain copies of the values of the `backward` *pointers*, pointing to the same stack-allocated objects that the originals' pointers point to.  Since these are different objects from the copies in the `adjacency` vectors, the elements of the adjacency vectors do not point to each other.

That is, just before the method returns, you have

- `e.backwards` points to `r`
- `r.backwards` points to `e`
- (a copy of `e` in `adjacency[v1]`)`.backwards` also points to `r`
- (a copy of `r` in `adjacency[v2]`)`.backwards` also points to `e`

Thus, in your example, performing `solve.adjacency[3][0].backwards->flow = 1` does not modify the object designated by `solve.adjacency[0][0]`, because the `backwards` pointer does not point to that object.  (In fact, the lifetime of the object to which it once pointed is over, so that assignment produces undefined behavior.)  It is not surprising, then, that you do not observe any change in `solve.adjacency[0][0]`.

There are several ways you could fix these problems, among them

- allocate the `Edge` objects on the heap, and store pointers to them in your vector
- assign `backward` pointers that point to the correct in-vector `Edges`

The latter can be implemented in `add()`, without modifying anything else; this should do it:

```
    void add(int v1, int v2, int c, int f){
        Edge e(v1, v2, c, f);
        Edge r(v2, v1, 0, 0);

        adjacency[v1].push_back(e);
        adjacency[v2].push_back(r);
        adjacency[v1].back().backwards = &adjacency[v2].back();
        adjacency[v2].back().backwards = &adjacency[v1].back(); 
    }
```