# what happens to the object after inserting to vector inside a function c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

When you declare a variable inside a block of code, then that variable has a lifetime that lasts until the end of the block of code. The variable will be destroyed when its lifetime ends, which is when control exits that block.

But in the case of std::vector, std::map....
When I do this kind of operation of push_back(, insert(
when doing it with a local variable is it made a copy of the object or just get the reference of it?

See the example bellow, on line list.push_back(a);

What I see in the console is

```
txt_0
txt_1
txt_2
```

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using std::iostream;

class A {
public:
    std::string txt;
};

class T {
public:
    std::vector<A> list;

    void test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            A a;
            a.txt = "txt_" + std::to_string(i);
            list.push_back(a);
        }
    }

    void show() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
        {
            std::cout << list[i].txt << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.test();
    t.show();
}
```

Comment: It is copied. Simple as that.

Comment: `push_back()`, `insert()`, etc insert *a copy* (initialised using a copy constructor) of the variable into the vector.   The copy is a different object from the variable, and its lifetime has no relationship to the lifetime of the variable.   Since C++11, variants of `push_back()`, `insert()`, that accepts a `T &&` will do a move, but those variants are not called when passing a named variable (e.g. they are used for unnamed temporaries).

Comment: I will quote from the classics: "Absolutely NOTHING!" -Lord Dark Helmet. "Nothing! Absolutely NOTHING!!" -Master Kuni.

Comment: [Is std::vector copying the objects with a push_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275076/is-stdvector-copying-the-objects-with-a-push-back)

Answer (score 0):

The [cppreference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) on `push_back` is reasonably clear about this:

> Appends the given element `value` to the end of the container.
>
> 1. The new element is initialized as a copy of `value`.
> 2. `value` is moved into the new element.

Comment: my object is a simple one, if it was a very large complex one with a lot of hiearchy, would it do a copy of it the same way ok?

Comment: Depending on the type of complexity, you may need to read up on [the rule of three/five/zero.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @felipe: "make a copy" means use either the copy constructor or the copy assignment operator (dependening on whether you're creating a new element (push_back) or assigning to an existing element).  For a complex object, these may be expensive and do just about anything.

Comment: You should also investigate [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

Comment: @felipe *would it do a copy of it the same way ok?* -- You do not need `vector` to test this.  Write a small `main` function that does this: `YourObject a;  YourObject a = b;  YourObject c; c = a;` -- Does this work correctly for YourObject?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie got it, it will use copy constructor or copy assignment so it will work in the case of vector too

Comment: @Chris I was reading that maybe using shared pointer would be the best way to handle this... std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> list;

Comment: @felipe "best" depends on how you measure better or worse.  Using shared_ptr means that you're copying (just) the shared_ptr when you copy something into/around the vector, which makes the copy cheaper, but makes any access more expensive.  It also changes the semantics in that two pointers might point to the same object.  `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` might be better.

Comment: If you want non-unique pointers stored in your vector, yes. Try to make your data structures make sense. If they don't, and you're trying to work around some behavior you don't like, it might mean the objects in your vector aren't designed properly. Be very careful about increasing the complexity of your code for the sake of minor optimizations.

Comment: @felipe -- Also, you have to make sure that the simple program has no memory leaks, no double-frees, no unexpected side-effects coded inside the copy and assignment, etc.  In other words, `YourObject` is safely copyable and assignable.  Also, that should be `YourObject b = a;` and not `YourObject a = b;`.