# Scope of C++ references and STL containers

Tags: c++, scope, reference, stl

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class SampleClass
{
    public:
        SampleClass(){}
        
        void ReceiveNewMessage()
        {
            const auto msg = GenerateSomeRandomMessage();
            StoreUniqueMessage(msg);
        }
        
    private:
        void StoreUniqueMessage(std::string msg)
        {
            messages.push_back(msg);
        }
    
        std::string GenerateSomeRandomMessage()
        {
            return "Random message";
        }
        
        std::vector<std::string> messages{};
    
};

int main() {
    
    SampleClass sc;
    
    sc.ReceiveNewMessage();

    return 0;
}
```

Clang is suggesting to use the following signature:

```cpp
void StoreUniqueMessage(const std::string& msg);
```

However, as references are an alias for its referent, the behaviour is undefined when the referent is destroyed (correct me if wrong); in this case, within `ReceiveNewMessage()`, the variable `msg` is local to this function, but, if I use a reference to it in `StoreUniqueMessage()`, wouldn't it be undefined behaviour when the function is out of scope? What am I missing about references?

Comment: as your internal storage is a `std::vector<std::string>` and not `std::vector<const std::string&>`, when `push_back` is called, a copy will be made. Changing the function signature to take a `const&`, will prevent one copy of the string, as it will not be copied for the function call but only when `push_back` is called.

Comment: [Is std::vector copying the objects with a push_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275076/is-stdvector-copying-the-objects-with-a-push-back)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `const std::string &msg` and a `std::vector<std::string> messages`, the operation `messages.push_back(msg);` makes a copy.

The vector owns its contents and takes care of them.

That the reference becomes invalid after that is no longer a problem.

If you had a vector of pointers to strings that someone else owns, the situation would be different.