# Do boost::shared_ptr<T> and boost::shared_ptr<const T> share the reference count?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

There are several interesting questions on pitfalls with `boost::shared_ptr`s. In one of them, there is the useful tip to avoid pointing `boost::shared_ptr<Base>` and `boost::shared_ptr<Derived>` to the same object of type `Derived` since they use different reference counts and might destroy the object prematurely.

My question: Is it safe to have both `boost::shared_ptr<T>` and `boost::shared_ptr<const T>` point to the same object of type `T`, or will this cause the same problem?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the Base/Derived claim?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701456/what-are-potential-dangers-when-using-boostshared-ptr/716112#716112

Comment: Base/Derive is 100% safe. It's unsafe to use `get()`. Here is analogous situation without Base: `shared_ptr<Derived> ptr(new Derived), ptr2(ptr.get());` -- unsafe.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Thanks, this was the example I always thought that was safe. You cleared up a severe misunderstanding of mine how boost::shared_ptr works..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is perfectly safe.

The following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main(int, char**)
{
  boost::shared_ptr<int> a(new int(5));
  boost::shared_ptr<const int> b = a;

  std::cout << "a: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b: " << b.use_count() << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiles and run fine, and is perfectly correct. It outputs:

```
a: 2
b: 2
```

The two `shared_ptr` share the same reference counter.

---

Also:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class A {};
class B : public A {};

int main(int, char**)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new B());
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b = boost::static_pointer_cast<B>(a);

    std::cout << "a: " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: " << b.use_count() << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Behave the same way. You must, however **never** build your `shared_ptr` using a construct like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> a(new B());
boost::shared_ptr<B> b(static_cast<B*>(a.get()));
```

`a.get()` gives the raw pointer and loses all information about reference counting. Doing this, you'll end up with two distinct (not linked) `shared_ptr` that use the same pointer but different reference counters.

Comment: Thanks, you are perfectly right. I had a completely different misunderstanding along the lines of ybungalobill's example. Thank you both!

Comment: I was about to post a question on casting shared_pointer but got the answer here. Thx.