# Is there a one line approach to declaring and initializing pointer variables?

Tags: c++, pointers, return, delete-operator

When I need to create a pointer variable, I currently use the following approach which works:

```
int getIntPointer()
{
    int * intPointer = new int;
    *intPointer = 0;

     return *intPointer;
}
```

likewise, when returning such a pointer from another function I would use something like this in main() to use it:

```
int main()
{
    int * intPointer = new int;
    *intPointer = getIntPointer();

    delete intPointer;
 }
```

This all works, but for readability and efficiency I'd like to know is if there are one line equivalents. (and I don't mean to just put them on the same line. I mean a short hand approach.)

Also: In this above example, I used the same pointer variable in both functions, and it works. Are they the same pointer in memory? Adding something like:

```
delete intPointer;
```

Immediately after the return statement doesn't crash the program, but does it even get there? Or is it safe to just delete it's passed iteration in main when no longer needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
int *intPointer = new int(0);
```

(or `new int(100);` if you want `intPointer` to point at the value 100).

And of course, you could shorten that to :

```
return new int(0);
```

assuming you don't need to do anything else with the pointer.

Note that:

```
int * intPointer = new int;
*intPointer = getIntPointer();
```

is incorrect. Either you mean:

```
int * intPointer = new int;
intPointer = getIntPointer();
```

in which case it's a memory leak, because you are overwriting `intPointer` from `new` with the one created by the call.

Or you mean to write:

```
int * intPointer = new int;
*intPointer = *getIntPointer();
```

in which case there is a memory leak because `getIntPointer` called `new` and you "lost" that pointer by not saving the return value.

For EVERY `new` you call, you should have exactly one corresponding `delete`, or it is a memory leak. Since both of my examples above does NOT provide that, because both cases will lose one of the pointers returned from `new`, this is incorrect.

In general, it is best to NOT use "raw pointers", and instead use either `std::unique_ptr` (if you only ever expect the pointer to "live" in one place at a time) or `std::shared_ptr` (if you expect multiple objects to have a copy of the pointer).

Edit: My answer above assumes that `getIntPointer` actually does what the name describes, rather than what the code in the question does, which is rather poor design: allocate memory and then return the pointed-to value.

Comment: What about the second question (about them being the same pointer in memory?)

Comment: Thank you! In class we were actually given 3 line examples and I couldn't find any references to doing it in just one line. This helps quite a bit! 

That wasn't a complete program >.< I was absolutely clear about that when I asked. I was just writing snippets for the sake of learning more. Obviously not having a delete is a memory leak, but I wanted to leave that portion aside for a separate matter.

Comment: The thing is, if I don't create it as new when returned the IDE throws multiple errors at me. Creating a duplicate is really the only way to actually use it, as far as I have been able to find, but I was concerned about memory leaks so I'd like to know the best approach for dealing with that situation. I have no intention of writing an ENTIRE program just to ask a question (again), so please try to understand that I was just giving an example. I'd like to know what to do at the end of the function and after it is used in main.

Comment: I would say if you are HAVING to call `new` for an `int` value, then you are almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: @Elliander It does now, apparently I arrived too early to your post :) thank you!

Comment: Of course the program is of poor design. It's not supposed to be an entire program.

Comment: If you pass a variable that was created in a function to main and then try to use it you will get an error: "undeclared identifier". Regardless, when dealing with getters, the value has to exist long enough to be returned - regardless of how it is used later in main. So the question was clearly focused in regards to this situation. I don't see why a question this simple requires so many complaints.

Comment: If I delete a variable after return, is it actually deleted? Or does the program not reach it?

Comment: I tested your approach and this works as well: `int * intPointer = new int(getIntPointer());` so if you can update your answer with a simple approach that should be taken with a pointer variable than needs to be returned (to delete it without interfering with the return) along with that snippet for the benefit of people who look on this page in the future I will vote yours as the answer

Comment: No, anything after a `return` will be skipped over [assuming it's not like `if (x == 7) return ... ; some more code;` - of course, some more code will execute if `x` is not 7]. So returning the value achieved from `new` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to delete it from Main? Or is it just a memory hole when it gets to that point? I'm running into these issues because I have a teacher that won't let me use non pointer variables. Obviously, this seems like a bad use case for pointers, but it's good to understand.

Comment: Assuming `getIntPointer` calls `new` as in your example code, that will STILL leak memory - there is no way that you can return what is pointed to, and the delete it - you have to copy the value, delete it, and then return.

Comment: You quite clearly need a different teacher. One that actually understands the language well enough to teach it, preferrably.

Comment: OK - copy the value, delete it, and then return. So you mean non pointer variables, right?

Comment: well the good news is that he isn't requiring it for all assignments. I think he's just trying to force us to deal with memory management. I will have a talk with him about this kind of memory leak though. I thought there was a problem, which is why I asked. I guess just edit with some details about why this is bad and how to avoid it so others facing a similar issue know what to do.

Comment: Yes, of course. And it's a REALLY bad idea to allocate memory for a single `int` value.

Comment: Right, without you posting a complete example, showing exactly what you want to have happen [and this is why a complete, verifiable example is so important], it's very hard to say what should or should not be done.

Comment: And I'm kind of lost as to what you want to have edited in the post - a suggestion as to "here's how you return a value from a leaky function, so that you can pass it to `new`"? Surely that's kind of obvious from the first code-snippet...

Comment: I guess so. It was obvious enough for me to get it from that snippet. I guess it works as is, and if someone wants more info they can read the comments later. OK.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I think you're reaching for `std::shared_ptr` and its helper function `std::make_shared`.

```
std::shared_ptr< int > intPointer = std::make_shared< int >( 42 );
```

Rather than repeat all the use cases of smart pointers here, I'll simply [link to an answer that goes into more detail on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657718/when-to-use-shared-ptr-and-when-to-use-raw-pointers)

inb4 rants about why smart pointers are good or bad.