# Is returning a raw pointer instead of unique_ptr good coding practice?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I've been studying unique_ptr and decided to write some simple code to make sure I've understood the concept and on how to use it. What I have below is a Manager class, which has a deque that contains unique_ptrs.

```
  class BaseClass
 {
    //...
 };

class Manager
{

public:

    std::list<BaseClass*> TempFuncName(Random Parameter)
    {
        std::list<BaseClass*> FoundObjects;

        for (ClassType::const_iterator iter(m_deque.begin()); iter != m_deque.end(); ++iter)
        {
            if(/*Do some checks using iter*/)
            {
                FoundObjects.push_back(iter->get());
            }
        }

        return FoundObjects;
    }

private:

    typedef std::deque<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> ClassType;
    ClassType m_deque;
};
```

So basically TempFuncName() will return a list of BaseClass pointers that satisfies some conditions. I've originally thought of having the TempFuncName return a list of unique_ptrs, but I felt that defeats the whole purpose of using unique_ptrs. So instead, I get the raw pointers of the unique_ptr and push_back() those raw pointers into the list and return that list.

I was just wondering if what I am doing (returning raw pointers instead of unique_ptrs) is actually good coding practice, or if it is okay to just return unique_ptrs (which I dont think is a good idea since) or if I shouldnt even use unique_ptrs in this situation.

I've tried googling but a lot of the posts I found didnt really discuss this particular question I had.

Any help and information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are cases where only a scalar will do, not a class that (very badly) emulates a scalar

Comment: Use `unique_ptr` to show the intent of ownership.  For parameters or return values, it codifies transferring ownership.  Use a raw pointer to show the intent of no ownership being transferred.  For a parameter, a raw pointer means "this could be nullptr, or could have a value" (if it can NEVER be nullptr, then use a reference instead).

Comment: So you have a situation where you want pointers on your deque and the same pointers returned from a search function. Seems to me that you should be using `std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>` since your pointers aren't unique. But it does depend on the *ownership* and *lifetime* of the pointers. If the pointers on the deque are always going to outlive the pointers returned from the function then you can say that the deque owns the pointers and then the code you have is good. But in general I think I'd go for shared pointers in a case like this.

Comment: @john Yeah, I want the Manager class to be the owner of the objects and no other pointers can point to the objects. I just wasnt sure if it was okay to return raw pointers since the Manager class owns the objects and returning a unique_ptr could potentially cause transferring ownership from where the function is called.

Comment: If the manager class will delete the objects then return raw pointers (and don't use them after the manager class is destroyed).

Comment: @JamesL Then what is the expected behaviour if `Manager` instance goes off and you still have pointers in hand and you access them?

Comment: @KunalPuri The Manager will be alive during the duration of the process so ideally when the process closes, the smart pointers will delete themselves as the Manager class gets destroyed.

Comment: @Galik I don't quite follow. The Manager class will always hold ownership of the objects and the manager will be "alive" until the process is exited. So there wouldnt be a case where the manager class will delete the objects and return the raw pointers.

Comment: @JamesL I am asking your opinion in case of raw pointers. If you had dynamically allocated `Manager` instance and you did `delete` to it. After doing so, Will you ever access pointers returned by `TempFuncName`?

Comment: I meant if you get pointers  before the manager is destroyed don't use those pointers after the manager has been deleted. But if the manager will **always** be deleted last then you are fine, use `std::unique_ptr` in the manager class and return raw pointers.

Comment: @KunalPuri No, the Manager class exists to maintain the unique_ptr objects so if the Manager instance gets deleted, the raw pointers that have been returned by the function wont be ever accessed (and the returned pointers wont be getting cached off. The function acts as a gettor function and the code that is calling this function will use the returned raw pointers and "forget" about them after its done).

Comment: This question has excellent answers but it not a precise duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657718/when-to-use-shared-ptr-and-when-to-use-raw-pointers

Answer (score 2):

> Is returning a raw pointer instead of unique_ptr good coding practice?

No. And yes. There is no answer, because it depends on context. It is fairly simple however:

Transferring ownership of a resource with a raw pointer is a bad coding practice.

Returning a non-owning pointer is a good practice (although in some cases a reference might be better).

These considerations are true in general, and remain true in your particular example. You must consider whether you intend to keep the objects within `Manager` or are you intending to transfer the ownership to the caller. You haven't removed the unique pointers in the function, so it appears that your intention is to not transfer the ownership. On the third hand, if you intend to share the ownership, then you need to use shared pointers throughout.

Answer (score 2):

Using raw **owning** pointer is bad practice.

Using raw observer pointer is fine... but as existing code might use Raw owning pointers, raw pointer is ambiguous between observer pointer and owning pointer.

Types such as [`std::experimental::observer_ptr<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) have been introduced to express intend clearly. (but it is basically just a pointer).

Observer pointers don't own data, so lifetime of the data should be longer than Observer pointer.

In your case, possible choices include:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    std::vector</*const*/ T*> filter_view_1(/**/) /*const*/;
    std::vector<std::experimental::observer_view</*const*/T>> filter_view_2(/**/) /*const*/;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper</*const*/T>> filter_view_3(/**/) /*const*/;


private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
};
```

So returned values should be used before that `Manager::data` is "cleaned".

Or, to guaranty lifetime:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr</*const*/T>> filter_view_4(/**/) /*const*/;
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr</*const*/T>> filter_view_5(/**/) /*const*/;


private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> data;
};
```

`filter_view_4` extend lifetime whereas `filter_view_5` allows to check lifetime of object.

There are also different approaches to not expose internal, such as:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    // std::function might be replaced by template for the Functor
    void for_each_filtered(std::function<bool(const T&)> filter,
                           std::function<void(/*const*/ T&)> action) /*const*/
    {
        for (auto& d : data) {
            if (filter(*d)) {
                action(*d)
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> data;
};
```

Comment: To clarify "introduced": Observer pointer has been adopted into the standard library extension technical specification; not incorporated into the draft of the upcoming standard (yet, and might not necessarily be ever).

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through some options of what you can return

If you return `unique_ptr`s, then *by definition* those objects are no longer being managed by the manager. It sounds like they still should be, so `unique_ptr` is not the right type.

If you return `shared_ptr`s, or `weak_ptr`s, then you can be sure that later changes by the manager won't suddenly invalidate your values. Either will mean that you change the queue to `shared_ptr`.

If you know *for sure* that these objects exist, for example because the `if` filtered out nulls, it would be really nice to return `BaseClass &`s. The problem is that you can't have a reference as the `value_type` of a container. In that case I would use `std::reference_wrapper<BaseClass>` as the contents of your container, although `BaseClass *` isn't much worse, as `reference_wrapper` is basically a pointer anyway.

If a null pointer is a valid option to return, you can't use references, so `BaseClass *` may be your best option.