# Moving local variable into return value of different type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, move

When returning values from a function in C++, we have copy elision and (Named) Return Value Optimization helping us create more efficient code. In short, the following code:

```
std::vector<int> make_vec_1(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(1e6);
    return v;
}
```

results in a silent move or direct construction into the destination of the return value, instead of a copy. The rules around this also mean that explicitly moving the returned object when returning actually prevents these optimizations.

```
std::vector<int> make_vec_2(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(1e6);
    return std::move(v); // BAD
}
```

This version prevents RVO, as explained in Scott Meyers' *Effective Modern C++*, Item 25.

---

My question is what happens when the return type is different, but can be move-constructed from one or more local variables? Consider the following functions that each return an optional vector:

```
std::optional<std::vector<int>> make_opt_vec_1(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(1e6);
    return v; // no move
}

std::optional<std::vector<int>> make_opt_vec_2(){
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(1e6);
    return std::move(v); // move
}
```

Which of these is correct? The line `return std::move(v)` looks like a red flag to me at first, but I also suspect it's the correct thing to do here. The same goes for the following two functions returning a pair of vectors:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> make_vec_pair_1(){
    std::vector<int> v1, v2;
    v1.resize(1e6);
    v2.resize(1e6);
    return {v1, v2}; // no move
}

std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> make_vec_pair_2(){
    std::vector<int> v1, v2;
    v1.resize(1e6);
    v2.resize(1e6);
    return {std::move(v1), std::move(v2)}; // move
}
```

In this case too, despite looking weird at first glance, I think moving into the return value is the better thing to do.

Am I correct that it's better to move into the return value when the types differ, but the return value can be move constructed from the local variable(s) being moved from? Have I misunderstood NRVO, or is there some other optimization that is well ahead of me here?

Comment: _This version results in a copy_ WUT?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer yes, I fat fingered that, my apologies. I meant that it prevents copy/move elision.

Comment: I am C++11 user, so my short answer woud be neither "yes", nor "no", but "does not matter!", because when it comes to `vector` (that's dynamic memory allocation) in C times we used pointers. Now we have `make_shared` things and could allocate buffers that may even be safely passed and shared between several producers/consumer threads, and you would essentially have zero-copy, sharing and deallocation. As per `optional` - I think that "converting C++ to JS" - is actually not a good idea. Why not just use JS for that kind of logic, and C/++ for some SSE/math code or low-level system interaction?

Comment: @xakepp35 What??

Comment: @xakepp35 Your comment makes very little sense. The biggest and most important change in C++11 is move semantics, and if you're truly a C++11 user, why do say it doesn't matter and then go on to talk about the history of C? Shared pointers have their downsides, namely a synchronization penalty for tracking ownership, and shared state which makes debugging harder. `optional` borrows much more strongly from languages like Haskell and C# (which have built-in, strongly-typed support for optional values) than it does from JavaScript (which lets you freely and carelessly put `null` anywhere).

Comment: Nope, its your example's use case - that makes no sense!!! Please just look at some [actual use cases, under notes section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). As for your code, i would insist on using `return make_shared< vector< ...` JUST because what you are doing is dynamically allocating a memory, **without knowing** who and how would use it - in such coding style when you want to pop out of a function some pointer, lyrically "allocated with `new[]`'  - its safer to return shared pointer!

Comment: Simpliest example: C++ HTTP Backend Server, 404 one-liner: `void handler_404(const& request) { async_respond_to_client( request.client, create_or_acquire_buffer(404, "Route " + request.url + " was not found")); }` Here `async_respond_to_client` is async function, that on completion would return buffer to the queue or dispose it. And `create_or_acquire_buffer` would create buffer if queue is empty, or acquire shared pointer from queue to save allocation, populate-n-return `shared_ptr`. That is an practical example of construction you shown; that has nothing to do with move semantics!

Comment: So I'm just about "each construct has its own niche, or use-cases": move has its cases, and returning a dynamically allocated pointer has its. And typically they do not intersect in a good program! So your example makes no sense - move semantics does not matter when returning vector - you typically wouldn't use them both at same time!

Comment: `"move has its cases, and returning a dynamically allocated pointer has its. And typically they do not intersect in a good program"` Goodness gracious, that is absurd. Are you familiar with how `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `string`, `vector`, etc, are typically implemented? Are you aware of what happens when you `return a_local_unique_ptr;` and why it works at all?

Comment: @xakepp35 I suggest you read through [this question about over-using `shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657718/when-to-use-shared-ptr-and-when-to-use-raw-pointers) to see how other developers feel about this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Am I correct that it's better to move into the return value when the types differ, but the return value can be move constructed from the local variable(s) being moved from? Have I misunderstood NRVO, or is there some other optimization that is well ahead of me here?

You did miss out on one thing. Even if the types differ, there will be an implicit move done automatically.

> **[class.copy.elision]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3) In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation
>   might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - **If the expression in a return statement is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression that names an object with automatic
>     storage duration declared in the body or parameter-declaration-clause
>     of the innermost enclosing function** or lambda-expression, or
> - if the operand of a throw-expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter)
>     whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost enclosing
>     try-block (if there is one),
>
> **overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue**. If the
>   first overload resolution fails or was not performed, or if the type
>   of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue
>   reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified), overload
>   resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue.
>   [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed
>   regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the
>   constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected
>   constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided.  — end
>   note ]

That is not contingent on the types matching, and is a fallback behavior in case full (N)RVO doesn't happen. You therefore gain nothing by moving explicitly in `make_opt_vec_2`.

Given that `std::move` is either a pessimization or entirely superfluous, I'd argue it's best *not* to do it when simply returning a function local object.

The only case where you'd want to write the move explicitly, is when the expression you return is more complex. In that case, you are indeed on your own, and not moving is a potential pessimization. So in `make_vec_pair_2`, moving into the pair *is* the correct thing to do.

The rule of thumb here is to not move just an id-expression that is a function local object. Otherwise, move away.

Comment: I can confirm with [this example program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/849b7d94b7b690d8) that it does depend on the complexity of the return expression. With two local variables being passed to the return expression, the moves are not happening implicitly. Where exactly is the line drawn then? Should "id-expression that names **an** object" be taken to mean "exactly one object?"

Comment: @alterigel - Precisely. In `return <expression>;`, the entire expression has to be an id-expression for this paragraph to apply. Sub-expressions don't apply. Although I'm fudging it a bit here, `{ ... }` is an initializer list, and not an expression per se, but the rule of thumb holds.

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping me understand the lawyer speak; it's not exactly my native tongue.