# boost::shared_* with copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have a class that contains a boost::shared_array member.  The other members are not dynamic - just a bunch of ints, no pointers.  I would expect that the default copy constructor for such a class would be fine.

This is my assumption:

1. Let's say I have an instance of this class, *orig*.
2. *orig*'s shared_array member has a reference count of 1.
3. Now I create a copy of orig:

   copy = orig;
4. I now expect both *copy* and *orig* to have shared_arrays that point to the same underlying memory, each with a reference count of 2.

Is the above correct?

I'm intimidated by various people who warn against the default copy constructor when there is a boost::shared_* member - but I can never find an explanation why the default would/could be bad.  For example, here's a comment by someone who says an explicit copy/assignment should be defined, but no explanation why:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/716112/629530

Can someone clarify when a copy constructor and assignment operator need to be defined for a class that contains boost::shared_* (shared_array and shared_ptr) members?

Comment: Technically, the default copy constructor is correct. However, it creates only shallow copy instead of a deep copy. But most people expect that copies are deep, i.e. independent of the original objects.

Comment: Thanks nosid.  Just for clarification, are you saying that my understanding from the example I gave is correct?  Regardless, I encourage you to flesh this out a bit more in a reply as I'll upvote  your answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following class uses the Pimpl Idiom in combination with a shared_ptr:

```
class location
{
    struct impl
    {
        double _latitude;
        double _longitude;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<impl> _impl;
public:
    location(double latitude, double longitude)
        : _impl{new impl{latitude, longitude}}
    { }
    void move_to(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        _impl->_latitude = latitude;
        _impl->_longitude = longitude;
    }
    // ...
};
```

The code compiles and works. However, there is a strange behaviour:

```
location london{51.51, 0.12};
location paris = london;
paris.move_to(48.86, 2.35);
std::cout << "London: " << london << '\n'; // prints 48.86/2.35
```

Changing the copy of an object also affected the original object. In this case, it is better to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`, because we would have been forced to write our own copy constructor.

There are also cases in which the behaviour of `std::shared_ptr` is desired. Let's add a member variable `metric` that will be used to calculate the distance between two locations (because there might be different strategies for calculating distances):

```
    std::shared_ptr<metric> _metric;
    double operator-(const location& rhs) const
    {
        return _metric->distance(*_impl, *rhs->_impl);
    }
```

In this case a `std::shared_ptr` works perfectly, because the metric is not part of the perceived state of the location, and there is no way to change the metric.

Comment: Very good, thanks!  Answer accepted. In addition to your comment, I make explicit that in both of your examples the "safety" associated with shared_ptr is not compromised even though the common resource is shared.  That is, london and paris will have the pointer deleted when both fall out of scope and not before.  The question, as you demonstrate, is whether this shallow copy of the shared memory location is desired or not.